# Allowing the attacker to access unathorized records finding

Tags: asp.net

I have a scan finding and hope someone can provide any ideas as to best ways to resolve the issue. First I will show the scan Finding then my code and finally what the scanner's recommended solution is.

**Finding**

Without proper access control, the method GetAttributeKey() in Provider.cs can execute a SQL statement on line 163 that contains an attacker-controlled primary key, thereby allowing the attacker to access unauthorized records.

Rather than relying on the presentation layer to restrict values submitted by the user, access control should be handled by the application and database layers. Under no circumstances should a user be allowed to retrieve or modify a row in the database without the appropriate permissions. Every query that accesses the database should enforce this policy, which can often be accomplished by simply including the current authenticated username as part of the query.

**My Code:**

**Offending line:**

myParam.SqlParam.Value = attribute;

**Method:**

```
public string GetAttributeKey(string attribute)
{
    string qry = "SELECT ws_attribute_key FROM webservice_attributes WHERE ws_attribute = @attribute";

    QueryContainer Instance = new QueryContainer(qry);

    MyParam myParam = new MyParam();

    myParam.SqlParam = new SqlParameter("@attribute", Instance.AddParameterType(_DbTypes._string));

    myParam.SqlParam.Value = attribute;

    Instance.parameterList.Add(myParam);

    object key = ExecuteScaler(Instance);

    return Convert.ToString(key);
}
```

**Scanner's Recommend fix:**

```
string user = ctx.getAuthenticatedUserName();
int16 id = System.Convert.ToInt16(invoiceID.Text);
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE id = @id AND user = @user", conn);
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
SqlDataReader objReader = query.ExecuteReader();
```

I think the problem is dealing with the code calling the GetAttributeKey. The method is called only if the user has no access to to the Attribute. I think I need some type of checking. Here is the calling code:

```html
            if (result.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                // get the attribute
                DataRow[] rows = result.Select("ws_attribute = '" + attribute + "'");
                if (rows.Length > 0)
                {
                    // check time range
                    string hr = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString();
                    DataRow[] valid = result.Select("ws_attribute = '" + attribute + "' AND start_time <= " + hr + " AND end_time >= " + hr);
                    if (valid.Length > 0)
                    {
                        ws_user_attribute_key = Convert.ToInt32(valid[0]["ws_user_attribute_key"].ToString());
                        ret = true;

                        // generate salt
                        TextEncryptor te = new TextEncryptor();
                        salt = te.CreateSalt(8);

                        // save to the log, return false if failed to log
                        if (!LogTransfer(ipAddress, accessDate, fileName, ws_user_attribute_key, salt, out logKey))
                            return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ret = false;
                        LogInvalidAccess(username, rows[0]["ws_attribute_key"].ToString(), ipAddress, accessDate, WSInvalidAccessReason.OutsideValidTimeRange);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // if user has no access to attribute
                    ret = false;
                    LogInvalidAccess(username, GetAttributeKey(attribute), ipAddress, accessDate, WSInvalidAccessReason.AttributeNotAccessible);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ret = false;
                LogInvalidAccess(username, GetAttributeKey(attribute), ipAddress, accessDate, WSInvalidAccessReason.InvalidAccount);
            }
```

Comment: Huh?  The sql from the two code snippets are completely different.

Comment: Question: does your query actually allow, with a random value of attribute, to read rows it wouldn't be authorized to read normally? If yes, what field would you have to add to the query's where clause to avoid this from happening? Because this looks like a very generic finding, possibly without any link to reality. It does happen (often) you know...

Comment: The scanner is showing a vulnerable example and a fix to the vulnerable example.   It is not suggesting updates to his code.  It is suggesting updates to the example code.

Comment: It is a valid warning, and yes, the example is only showing you how you could address the warning.  This gives you row level security on the table you are running the query against.

Comment: @Rogala it is valid, provided the database table actually has a field to narrow-down the select. But that's something only OP can tell us.

Comment: And what's your actual question?

Comment: @fvu: I said it was a valid warning, and the example is showing how to add the user level security into the query.  The scanner doesn't know the db schema, so it's giving a generic example to show how to create row/record level security.

Comment: This finding was determined to be changed to a mitigated warning and was remove as a valid finding. Showing that the caller needs rights to call the method when they are logged into the system is a false finding.